# State not changing to false from true value reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am a newbie to reactjs. Currently i am trying to set the state of input_active to true or false based on onBlur and onFocus events. Based on input_active value i change the style of input element.

Below is the code snippet,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input_text_ref = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        input_active: 'true',
    };
}
focus = () => {
    console.log("focus");
    this.setState({input_active: 'true'});
    console.log("input_active_focus", this.state.input_active);
};

blur = () => {
    console.log("blur");
    this.setState({input_active: 'false'});
    console.log("input_active_blur", this.state.input_active);
};

render() {
    let input_element_classes = [''];

    if(!this.state.input_active)//out of focus {
        input_element_classes.push('blur');
    }
    if (this.state.input_active) //focused input element {
        input_element_classes.pop();
        input_element_classes.push('focus');
    }


    return (
        <div className={'text_input_wrapper'}>
            <input {...rest}
                className={input_element_classes.join(' ')}
                type="text"
                ref={this.input_text_ref}
                onChange={this.handle_text_input_change}
                onBlur={this.blur}
                onFocus={this.focus}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Below is the css,

```
.focus {
    background-color:green;
}
.blur {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The problem even on focus on blur the value of this.state.input_active is always true...How do i change its value based on focus and blur. Thanks.

Comment: `'false' != false`

Comment: Hello, setState is async so if you want to set state and print it you have to do it like this : this.setState({nameofstate: value}, () => console.log(this.state.nameofstate))

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, especially the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input_text_ref = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        input_active: true,
    };
}
focus = () => {
    console.log("focus");
    this.setState({input_active: true});
    console.log("input_active_focus", this.state.input_active);
    //HERE you will not get updated state as setState is Async
};

blur = () => {
    console.log("blur");
    this.setState({input_active: false});
    console.log("input_active_blur", this.state.input_active);//SAME reason as above
};

render() {
    //NO need of an array here
    let input_element_classes = ''blur'';
    const {input_active} = this.state;
    if(input_active)//out of focus {
        input_element_classes = 'focus';
    }
    return (
        <div className={'text_input_wrapper'}>
            <input {...rest}
                className={input_element_classes}
                type="text"
                ref={this.input_text_ref}
                onChange={this.handle_text_input_change}
                onBlur={this.blur}
                onFocus={this.focus}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This answer might be correct, but it doesn't educate the asker. Don't just post a wall of code as the answer.

Comment: Added USeful comments also in between the code please check @DanielHilgarth

Comment: Better, but the are hard to see and it is not evident that they are from you and not from the asker. Also, the main point `'false'`vs `false` you didn't event comment on as far as I can see

Comment: if(input_active) should be focus element meaning input_active is true right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `true` and `false`, not `'true'` and `'false'`.

You are assigning strings to `state.input_active`. A string always evaluates to `true` if it is not empty. Even if the string is `'false'`.